# ssh remote command execution when passed with -t containing an empty variable is switching user and not printing requested remote command output

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, centos

In our environment we use standard ssh commands for remote execution and the ssh command is broke when "-t" option is passed with emtpy value. Below is an an example

```
[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# value=
[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# echo $value

[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# /usr/bin/ssh -k moduser@vm01 -t "$value" /usr/bin/svn info http://vm01/repos
[moduser@pcrfclient01 ~]$
```

As shown above instead of printing the output, the ssh command is simply switching as the other user which is not the case in our second environment and below is the output from our second(working) environment

```
[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# value=
[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# echo $value

[root@pcrfclient01 ~]# /usr/bin/ssh -k moduser@vm01 -t "$value" /usr/bin/svn info http://vm01/repos
Path: repos
URL: http://vm01/repos
Relative URL: ^/
Repository Root: http://vm01/repos
Repository UUID: f5951489-d042-471b-824d-2a6a8692d78f
Revision: 412
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: moduser-svn
Last Changed Rev: 412
Last Changed Date: 2021-07-21 12:50:48 +0000 (Wed, 21 Jul 2021)
```

This $value variable is part of our script and will always come as empty and it is used in so many of our scripts, so I want to hold those changes and ensure that my problematic environment works the same way as my stable environment. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `-t` doesn't take any option arguments.

Comment: @Roadowl We are passing some passthru values in -t parameter. Problem is that passthru values not always comes with a value and sometimes it comes as null as per our environment code structure. So like I said, on the other environment even with null values ssh command is working, but here it is simply connecting as a different user which is wrong. So any idea on how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue and the problem is my team recently updated the shell info for moduser in /etc/passwd and changed it to sudosh by mistake

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -i moduser
moduser:x:500:500::/home/moduser:/bin/sudosh
```

So I changed this back to to /bin/bash and post that ssh command is accepting null values and was able to print the remote command outputs successfully

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -i moduser
moduser:x:500:500::/home/moduser:/bin/bash
```

However I still don't know why having sudosh for my user is making me switch the user instead of printing the output of remote commands.